# Awkward phrase structure

Tags: sentence, sentence-patterns

I am trying to convey the following idea:

> "fruit species of a kind that people commonly eat the fruits
>   themselves, as well as drink the juice extracted from them (for example, grapes and apples)."

However, no matter how much I try, the wording sounds extremely awkward. Can anyone suggest an elegant way of writing this? Thanks.

Comment: Common fruits used for both eating and drinking.

Comment: @KristinaLopez - is it really correct to say that the fruit is "used for drinking"?

Comment: If you had to fit it in a tweet, I'm pretty sure the intent would be understood.  Further explanation starts getting into the cumbersome trap of "from which juice is extracted and drunk", etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for writing advice.

Answer (score 2):

"Fruits that are commonly eaten and whose juice is commonly drank"

"Juice" might be replaced by "extract"

Or:

"Fruits that are commonly consumed, both as food and as juices"

Comment: I like the your last suggestion.

Comment: Good suggestions. Are you sure that the correct usage is "drank" rather than "drunk"?

Comment: I am not sure, I think you're right, drunk is probably correct. I'll edit.  Edit: I'm actually not a hundred percent sure either way, I did some research, it looks like drunk is more common but not necessarily more correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Is [edible](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/edible) fruits not suitable for that ?

> fit to be eaten; eatable

That also the title used in WP for that kind of fruits:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Edible_fruits

Comment: Not really the same idea... there are many things that are "edible" yet not commonly eaten.

Comment: Common edible fruits then...?

Comment: Dandelions are "common edible plants" - but they are not commonly eaten (at least not in my part of town).

Comment: well "common" is always dependant on context. Common worldwide, common in a country, common in your town...You 're looking for something that "people commonly eat"...

Comment: Exactly -- Commonly eaten, not just commonly found.

Answer (score 0):

How about "fruits that are commonly eaten and juiced"?

"Juiced" has slang meaning as well, so you may not want to use it for that reason.

> [juiced](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/juiced): [verb] to extract juice from

Comment: This is quite close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. The point I am trying to convey is that people commonly _consume_ the juice, not just that the fruit is commonly juiced.